# Class inheritance: Constructor and member functions of class not recognized by compiler

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, constructor

I just ran into trouble with my code of class inheritance: the constructors are not recognized by the compiler. Neither are any member functions.
For example, if I call the constructor,
my testfile(test.cpp) starts like this:

```
#include "salariedemployee.h"//This is a class inherited from 'employee.h', the base class
#include "Administrator.h"//This is a class inherited from "salariedemployee.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using namespace employeessavitch;
int main()
{
    Employee boss("Mr Big Shot","987-65-4321");//I try to call constructor in the base class "employee";
}
```

The compiler gives an error like

```
undefined reference to `employeessavitch::Employee::Employee(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >)'
```

If I try to call the constructors in inherited class such as

```
SalariedEmployee boss("Mr Big Shot","987-65-4321",10500.50);//a constructor about name, SSN number, and salary
```

it gives an error like:

```
undefined reference to `employeessavitch::SalariedEmployee::SalariedEmployee(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, double)'
```

I would like to know what is going wrong?

My base class header file is written as :

```
#ifndef EMPLOYEE_H
#define EMPLOYEE_H
#include <string>
using namespace std;
namespace employeessavitch
{
  Employee( );//default constructor
  Employee(string the_name, string the_ssn); constructor about name and ssn
}#endif
```

My inherited class header file is written as:

```
#ifndef SALARIEDEMPLOYEE_H
#define SALARIEDEMPLOYEE_H
#include <string>
#include "employee.h"
using namespace std;
namespace employeessavitch
{
    class SalariedEmployee : public Employee
    {
        public:
           SalariedEmployee( );//default constructor
           SalariedEmployee (string the_name, string the_ssn, double the_weekly_salary);//constructor about name, ssn and salary
           //Other member function and variables are ommitted here.
}#endif
```

I am pretty sure that the namespace is all right as I can write std cin and cout.

My cpp file of implementation was like:

```
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include "employee.h"
using namespace std;
namespace employeessavitch
{
   Employee::Employee( ) : name("No name yet"), ssn("No number yet"), net_pay(0)
   {
     //deliberately empty
   }
 }
```

and

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "salariedemployee.h"
using namespace std;
namespace employeessavitch
{
    SalariedEmployee::SalariedEmployee( ) : Employee( ), salary(0)
    {
    //deliberately empty
    }
    SalariedEmployee::SalariedEmployee(string the_name, string the_number, double the_weekly_salary): Employee(the_name, the_number), salary(the_weekly_salary)
    {
      //deliberately empty
    }
 }
```

Comment: It means you need to link your Employee.cpp and SalariedEmployee.cpp properly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the Employee constructors are not declared as part of the class definition.

Try this in employee.h:

```
namespace employeessavitch
{
  class Employee
  {
    public:
    Employee( );//default constructor
    Employee(string the_name, string the_ssn); //constructor about name and ssn
  };
}
```

Comment: I have it in a separate .cpp file, exactly the same

Comment: `namespace employeessavitch

{

    Employee::Employee( ) : name("No name yet"), ssn("No number yet"), net_pay(0)

    {

        //deliberately empty

    }}`

Comment: Where is the Employee class declared ? I can see you are defining your constructor with Employee::Employee(), but where is the class definition please..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16005322/c-class-inheritance-undefined-reference-to-classconstructor

Answer (score 0):

Undefined reference simply means that even though it is getting the function definitions (i.e. from header file), it is not getting the implementation for the functions (`SalariedEmployee` and `Employee`). Did you implement the function in the .cpp file for `Employee(string the_name, string the_ssn);`?

Comment: I think I did the implementation for both classes for that constructor.

Comment: I hope you mean to say that classes as well as the methods inside it ?? it wud be better if you share the code for cpp file where you have implemented the class which contains this functions implementation

Answer (score 0):

The code below should work (do this for your other class also):

```
#ifndef EMPLOYEE_H
#define EMPLOYEE_H
#include <string>
using namespace std;
namespace employeessavitch
{
  Employee( )
  {
  }//default constructor
  Employee(string the_name, string the_ssn)// constructor about name and ssn
  {
  }
}#endif
```

Alternatively, if you believe that you already have an implementation defined in your .cpp file then check to make sure that the parameters match. The cpp implementation should look like:

```
employeessavitch::Employee::Employee()
{
}

employeessavitch::Employee::Employee(string the_name, string the_ssn)
{
}
```

Also, it is best not to have a 'using namespace' statement in your header file. The reason is that this means that any code that includes this header file is automatically using the namespace which sort of defeats the purpose. If you don't want to have a cpp file then use the 'std::' prefix instead of 'using namespace std' in your header file.

I wasn't quite sure from the question whether or not you have a separate .cpp file that includes the constructor implementations. If you do, posting it would be helpful in trying to assist with your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the definition of both cstors to your employee.cpp file.

This one wasn't defined:

```
    Employee(); //cstor
    Employee( string the_name, string the_ssn); // <-- This one isn't defined
```

Add both cstor definitions to your file and it compiles:

```
    #include <string>
    #include <cstdlib>
    #include <iostream>
    #include "employee.h"

    using namespace std;
    namespace employeessavitch
    {
       Employee::Employee( ) : name("No name yet"), ssn("No number yet"), net_pay(0)
       {
         //deliberately empty
       }

       Employee::Employee( string the_name, string the_ssn) // <-- is missing in
       {                                                    //     your cpp file 
         //deliberately empty
       }
    }
```